# toString() Error, Cannot resolve method toString()

Tags: java, search, methods, tostring

I am trying to convert the int id I get back from a model called Part in a search functionality I am building to a string so I can simplify the search.

Here is the if statement I have used so far:

```
if(part.getId().toString().indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
return true;}
```

When I try to convert this id to a string, I am shown an error that says `Cannot resolve method toString()`

Here is the get method in the Part model I am using:

```
public int getId() { return id; }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

I am using JavaFX 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a method on primitive types like `double`, `int`, `float` in Java.

Use `String.valueOf(part.getId())` instead.

Comment: One trick I sometimes use is to add the value to a string, e.g. `"" + part.getId()`, that will get the string value regardless of whether it is an object or a primitive, though I guess internally it is similar to calling [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(boolean)), given `valueOf` is an overloaded function which works with both objects and primitives.

Comment: Also `Integer.toString(part.getId())`.